# Operating aes-128-cbc encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, openssl, aes

I am doing encryption with aes-128-cbc with the following command:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in input.ts -out output.ts -p -nosalt -iv {something} -K {something}
```

The above command can be executed in both Window and Linux.

Now, I would like to transform it into C#. However, when I look at the man page of C# and the examples from google, there are different implementations. I am confused in **Aes** and **AesCryptoServiceProvider** class. Also, **Rijndael** and **RijndaelManaged** classes, as well as **RijndaelManagedTransform**.

What is the difference between mentioned classes and which one is the best for me accomplish my task?